# vector addition using R

Tags: r

I have multiple vectors of same length named as:

```
c1
c2
c3
.
.
cn
```

is there any way to make a single vector "c" have summation of all elements of c1 to cn i.e.

```
c = c1+c2+c3+c4..........cn
```

Comment: You mean like `sum(c)`?

Comment: my vector names are c1, c2, c3, upto n
i want to write a function where i can assign say n=5
c = submission of ("c",1:n)

Comment: It's generally bad practice to name a variable `c`, because of the `c(...)` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ls()` to list all variables in the global environment and restrict the output of it by `pattern` argument. Then get values of those variables using `mget` and row bind the values of the list using `rbind` and get row sum using `rowSums` function.

```
# create sample vectors
c1 <- c(1, 2)
c2 <- c(2, 4) 
c3 <- c(3, 2)
c30 <- c(1, 30)

c_vars <- ls(pattern = "c[0-9]", name = .GlobalEnv )  # to get values for name argument, try search()
c_vars
# [1] "c1"  "c2"  "c3"  "c30"

n <- 2   # specify the value of n
c_vars <- c_vars[c_vars %in% paste("c", 1:n, sep = '')]   # subset only the variables matching from 1:n

c_vars
# [1] "c1" "c2"
```

Two ways to get the sum of each selected vector.

```
# 1. It will work only when all vectors are of same length
rowSums(do.call("rbind", mget( c_vars ) ))
# c1 c2 
#  3  6 

# 2. It will work regardless of length of vectors.   
unlist(lapply(mget(c_vars), sum))
# c1 c2 
#  3  6
```

Comment: if c1 = c(1,2), c2 = c(2,4)     sum(c_all) should be c(3,6) but using your code it will be 9